# std::back_inserter for a std::set?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I guess this is a simple question. I need to do something like this:

```
std::set<int> s1, s2;
s1 = getAnExcitingSet();
std::transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), std::back_inserter(s2), ExcitingUnaryFunctor());
```

Of course, `std::back_inserter` doesn't work since there's no `push_back`.
`std::inserter` also needs an iterator? I haven't used `std::inserter` so I'm not sure what to do.

Does anyone have an idea?

---

Of course, my other option is to use a vector for `s2`, and then just sort it later. Maybe that's better?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

`set` doesn't have `push_back` because the position of an element is determined by the comparator of the set. Use `std::inserter` and pass it `.begin()`:

```
std::set<int> s1, s2;
s1 = getAnExcitingSet();
transform(s1.begin(), s1.end(), 
          std::inserter(s2, s2.begin()), ExcitingUnaryFunctor());
```

The insert iterator will then call `s2.insert(s2.begin(), x)` where `x` is the value passed to the iterator when written to it. The set uses the iterator as a hint where to insert. You could as-well use `s2.end()`.

Comment: Since `inserter(vec, vec.end())` works for vectors, too, why does anyone use back_inserter in the first place?

Comment: @NHDaly: because back_inserter is faster

Comment: @marton78 But shouldn't it only be faster by a very small margin, if at all? Calling `insert` instead of `push_back` on a vector should be roughly identical (O(1)) when no elements have to be moved.

Comment: @FelixDombek you are right, it won't be a lot slower. `v.insert(x, v.end())` will have an additional branch at the beginning (due to it moving n elements, but here n is zero). However, using `inserter` 1) communicates a different intent than using `push_back` 2) is unusual and makes the reader stop and think 3) is a premature pessimization.

Comment: @marton78 why is there no specialization for `std::back_inserter<std::set>` which would call `std::inserter(set, set.end())`? This would allow for more generic code

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik if you insert something that the Comparitor evaluates less than the last value, then it won't be inserted into the back, but will be placed in order. 
With back_inserter, the element is always placed at the end of the container.

Comment: @trozzel your conclusion is kind of misleading. You should have said instead that `back_inserter` would be not possible to implement, hence it would not make any sense to have it in the first place. But hey, the STD library has a lot of things that does not make sense. One of them is `back_inserter(set)` itself. You get an error only when you try to dereference it.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik It's impossible to have a back_inserter(set<T>), because back_inserter requires that the container posses a push_back method, of which std::set does not have.

Comment: @trozzel it is possible to have `back_inserter(set<T>);` https://godbolt.org/z/dYGYj3v4j It is only not possible to call a dereference operator. But the construction should not be able to compile in the first place with some neat compile-time error.

Answer (score 4):

In 2016 there was a proposal to have a "single argument `inserter` iterator".
https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0471r0.html . I couldn't find if it the proposal advanced. I think it makes sense.

For now you can have this behavior defining the maker function:

```
template<class Container>
auto sinserter(Container& c){
    using std::end;
    return std::inserter(c, end(c));
}
```

Used as:

```
std::transform(begin(my_vec), end(my_vec), sinserter(my_set), [](auto& e){return e.member;});
```

Comment: Is this intended to work on all the standard containers?  It doesn't work on std::forward_list (the compiler error is "forward_list has no member named 'insert'", inside instantiation of `insert_iterator::operator=`).  Should it?

Comment: @DonHatch, anything that has `insert` (and `end`). it seems that `forward_list` doesn't have an `insert` operation in the first place, only `insert_after`. And even if that is changed it can not be inserted after the end, I think. Can't you use a `std::list` instead?

Comment: Sure, I personally have no need for std::forward_list.  But I'm interested in a generic "how do I copy one container to another?"  for all pairs of containers for which it makes sense.  My current interest is for exercising generic container allocators such as @HowardHinnant 's short_alloc.

Comment: @DonHatch, the thing is that there are many variants to that question. (""how do I copy one container to another?"). For example, do you want to preserve the original values, do you want to minimize allocations, etc. For the simplest case the best answer in my opinion is to use the constructor the container that takes two iterators (most containers can take that). `NewContaner new_container(old_other_container.begin(), old_other_container.end())`.

Comment: For sequential containers, yes it seems natural to preserve the original order, like the constructors do; and, similarly, I'd expect number of allocations to be commensurate with what the constructor or std::copy does.  I'd prefer to be able to do it into an existing container, but, failing that, you're right, it does look like all the sequential containers do have that same constructor interface (and, as of c++14, they all also allow an optional allocator to be specified, which is important for my use case), so that may be my best bet.  Thanks!

Comment: @DonHatch, not necessarily, `set` doesn't perserve the order (`std::set<T> new_set(c.begin(), c.end()`) and that is fine. Also creating a "new" container and moving it into an existing one is something quite sane to do these days. `existing_list = std::list(c.begin(), c.end())`. Value semantics is great. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, std::set isn't a SequentialContainer, and that's fine :-)  `existing_list = std::list(c.begin(), c.end(), existing_list.get_allocator())`  Very nice, I think that's my answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @DonHatch yes, missed the word “sequential”. I just remember that most containers have an `assign` member precisely for that. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/assign