# Creating a set of strings from a vector<T>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda, set

I have a vector of `CustomClass` objects - which have string field called `name`. How do I create a `set` of these names in C++ ?

If I do this :

```
std::vector<CustomClass> vec ;
// .... populate with data
std::set< std::string> myset( vec.begin(), vec.end() ) ;
```

compiler will complain of course, but how can I "apply" a function so that I get "vec.name" from each element of the vector for example?

I am using C++11.

Comment: [Different question, but maybe same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/908272/3484570).

Comment: @nwp so do that in two steps - first create a set of CustomClass and then use transform?

Comment: That is what I would do. Alternatively you can write a custom `vector_iterator_wrapper` that returns `vec_it->name` when dereferenced, but that seems like a lot of work for no gain. You could also make `CustomClass` be implicitly convertible to a `std::string`, but that is very dodgy.

Comment: Another simple way, is just create a simple for loop over your vector vec, inserting each element to myset. Like this: for (const CustomClass &c : vec){myset.insert(c.name);}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (since C++11), e.g.

```
std::set<std::string> myset;
std::transform(vec.begin(), 
               vec.end(), 
               std::inserter(myset, myset.end()), 
               [](const CustomClass& cc) { return cc.name; });
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HG1PRetAdfLVu8Wi)

Comment: C++'98 uses a function here. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

A good old loop (in version c++11 range based) should do the job

```
for ( auto const & cc : vec )
   myset.emplace(cc.name);
```

Comment: @songyuanyao - D'oh! You're right, obviously. Corrected in `emplace()`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class demo
{
    public:
    string name;
    void input()
      {
         cout<<"\n Enter the Name:";
         cin>>name;

      }
      void output()
      {
          cout<<"\n Name is :"<<name;
      }

};
int main()
{
vector <demo> d1(3);
demo *d2;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    d2=new demo;
    d2->input();
    d1.push_back(*d2);
}
vector<demo>::iterator j;

for( j=d1.begin();j!=d1.end();j++)
   {
      j->output();
  }

 return 0;

}
```

try this above coding it will get the value and store it the vector which contains class objects.
vector  d1(3) --> creates a vector variable d1 for the class demo with size 3. create a another pointer variable d2 through which input function is called and values are given and the class object address is stored in vector.
create iterator variable to access the values of stored values.
Thank you